# Why "if alive?(pid)" always rerurn TRUE inside Open3.popen3

Tags: ruby

Why "if alive?(pid)" always rerurn TRUE inside Open3.popen3? Of course, we can use "Process.kill('KILL', wait_thr.pid) rescue" but what has caused this behavior?

```
def alive?(pid)
    Process.kill(0, pid)
        true
    rescue
        false
end

def start_live(username)
unless [nil, '', 0].include?(username)
    Open3.popen3("livestreamer twitch.tv/#{username} source") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
        pid = wait_thr.pid
        while line=stdout.gets do
            if line =~ /.*Starting.*/
                print 'Запускаем..  '
                sleep 5
                #ruby -e "puts Signal.list"
                Process.kill('KILL', pid) if alive?(pid)
                url_chat(username.downcase)
                puts "Готово."
                return
            elsif line =~ /^error: No streams.*/
                puts 'Похоже стрим OFF-line или ты ошибся в Нике.'
            end
        end
    end
else
    puts "Такого номера нет в списке."
end
```

end

Comment: `alive?` can only return `false` when `Process.kill(0, pid)` raises an exception. Why do you expect it to raise an exception?

Comment: @spickermann >>alive? can only return false when Process.kill(0, pid) raises an exception. 
That's right, but always performed Process.kill('KILL', pid), i don't understand it.
    >>ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: Since `alive?(pid)` always returns `true`, the inline `if` is the same than `Process.kill('KILL', pid) if true`. Which means: Always run `Process.kill('KILL', pid)`.

Comment: Well, what's wrong with my alive? it returns TRUE if PID not running.